# Multiple upload put image names in same database row

Tags: php

hi i have this script that works great but now im trying to get it to add the names of the 3 images to my database in the same database row if you upload 3 images the $extension will show the 3 names of the images but i have no idea how to get the 3 names into the same database row under image1 , images2, images3 anyone have any idea how this can be done? i tried everything i know of with no luck thanks.

```
`$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "????", "????");
mysql_select_db("????", $connection);
$uploaddir = "upload/";
$MaxSize = "600000";
$number_of_files = count($_FILES['userfile']);
for($i=0;$i<=$number_of_files;$i++) {
$filename_format = uniqid(Img_);
if (!$_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] == 0)
{
if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $MaxSize)
{
echo "ERROR: file too big";
exit;}
$tempfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
$uploadfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
$extension = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
if (strstr($extension,"jpeg"))
{
$extension=".jpg";
}
elseif (strstr($extension,"gif"))
{
$extension=".gif";
}
elseif (strstr($extension,"png"))
{
$extension=".png";
}
else
{
echo "ERROR: Only gif/jpeg/png allowed.";
exit;
}
if(copy($tempfile, $uploaddir.$uploadfile))
{
echo "Copy Successfull!";
}
else
{
echo "ERROR: something happened trying to copy the temp file to the folder";
}
if(rename($uploaddir.$uploadfile,$uploaddir.$filename_format.$extension))
{
}else{
$query = "INSERT INTO photos (image1, image2, image3) VALUES ('WHAT TO PUT      HERE?','HERE','AND HERE')";  
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo " and renamed to $filename_format$extension";
}
}
else
{
echo "ERROR: Problem renaming the file.. $uploadfile";
}
}`.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a good database design.  What if someone uploads four images?  What if they upload ten?  That approach complicates the code, because you have to deal with multiple columns for the same thing, and also imposes an arbitrary limit on how many values you can store.

It'd be better to use a separate database record for each uploaded file.  If you want to indicate that a group of files were all uploaded "together", make a photo_groups table whose rows represent sets of photos uploaded together, and have each record in the photos table include the ID of a record in the photo_groups table.  That way you can have multiple photo records associated with a single photo group.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to put variable numbers of columns in a given row (in fact, as far as I know, it's impossible with most flavors of SQL).

If, for example, you have a forum post that has attachments, you should do something like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Table `forum_posts`                         |
+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
| post_name | post_content | etc... | post_id |
+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
| "Example  | "Blah blah   | ...    |    5    |
|  post"    |  blah..."    |        |         |
+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
```

where post_id is an auto-incrementing primary key (which basically means that each row in this table has a unique post_id), you should put your images in a new table, like so:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| Table `forum_post_images`                    |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| image_url  | image_name | post_id | image_id |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| image1.png | "Lol!"     |   10    |     1    |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| image2.jpg | "asdf"     |   1     |     2    |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| image3.gif | "Example"  |   3     |     3    |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Here, each image has a unique ID (just in case we ever need it), and an id of the post that it belongs to. Now you can do two separate queries to load a forum post and its attached images:

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_posts` WHERE `post_id` = 5;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_post_images` WHERE `post_id` = 5;
```

This will return, in two queries, the post information and the images attached to it. You can modify this sort of design for your particular application using the same approach.